# CAML Query with AND OR

Tags: caml-query, spservices, caml

I'm struggling to get a simple query working and would appreciate any assistance in pointing out my error/s.

I need to return all "Chart Type" that equal "Jacket" for "2016" in both "Mar" and "Feb".

```
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <And>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='Chart_x0020_Type' />
                    <Value Type='Choice'>Jacket</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='Year' />
                    <Value Type='Text'>2016</Value>
                </Eq>
                <And>
                    <Or>
                        <Eq>
                            <FieldRef Name="Month" />
                            <Value Type='Text'>Mar</Value>
                        </Eq>
                        <Eq>
                            <FieldRef Name="Month" />
                            <Value Type='Text'>Feb</Value>
                        </Eq>
                    </Or>
                </And>
            </And>
        </Where>
    </Query>
```

Using a SP CAML builder I only get errors so I'm sure I've approached this incorrectly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your first `<And>` have three child clauses. That's not permitted. One `<And>` (or one `<Or>`) must have exactly two children. You then must nest all clauses so you only have two clauses in any `<And>` or `<Or>`.
2. If you run this query from an `SPQuery` class (i.e. you set your CAML string into `mySPQuery.Query` property), you must get rid of the `<Query>` tag. The first level must be `<Where>`.

So, your CAML query must be rewritten as this:

```
<Where>
  <And>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name='Chart_x0020_Type' />
      <Value Type='Choice'>Jacket</Value>
    </Eq>
    <And>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Year' />
        <Value Type='Text'>2016</Value>
      </Eq>
      <Or>
        <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name="Month" />
          <Value Type='Text'>Mar</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name="Month" />
          <Value Type='Text'>Feb</Value>
        </Eq>
      </Or>
    </And>
  </And>
</Where>
```

As you can see:

- The first `<And>` encapsulates one `<Eq>` and another `<And>`.
- That second `<And>` has also two children: another `<Eq>` and a `<Or>`.
- Finally the `<Or>`has two children itself: the two inner `<Eq>`.

Answer (score 1):

Look this,

```
<Query>
<Where>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Chart_x0020_Type' />
            <Value Type='Choice'>Jacket</Value>
        </Eq>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Year' />
            <Value Type='Text'>2016</Value>
        </Eq>
    <Or>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="Month" />
            <Value Type='Text'>Mar</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="Month" />
            <Value Type='Text'>Feb</Value>
        </Eq>
    </Or>
    </And>
</And>
</Where>
</Query>
```

Remove "Query" tag from above query before assign it to SPQuery.query

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this query**

```
 <Query>
    <Where>
       <And>
         <And>
             <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Chart_x0020_Type' />
                <Value Type='Choice'>Jacket</Value>
             </Eq>
             <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Year' />
                <Value Type='Text'>2016</Value>
             </Eq>
         </And>
         <Or>
             <Eq>
                 <FieldRef Name="Month" />
                 <Value Type='Text'>Mar</Value>
             </Eq>
             <Eq>
                 <FieldRef Name="Month" />
                 <Value Type='Text'>Feb</Value>
             </Eq>
         </Or>
       </And>
    </Where>
 </Query>
```

Design your CAML query using tool to get exact query which you wants to achive..

[U2U Caml Query Builder](http://www.u2u.be/Software)